# How to add banner and how to get master page in sharepoint of office365?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365, master-page, customization

I am trying to get the default master page in Office 365 SharePoint site. Where I can find the master page in office 365?

Also, I need to add the second image as an banner on SharePoint. How can I achieve this?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]